# How to retreive the control type of Automation Element with plain C

Tags: c, com, ui-automation

**Objective:** Get the control type name as string (ie. Button, Checkbox, Menu, MenuItem, and so on) from an Uiautomation element by means of plain C

I have the following code so far:

```
#define COBJMACROS
#include "UiAutomationClient.h"
#include "UiAutomationCore.h" 

POINT pt;
IUIAutomation *pAutomation = NULL;
IUIAutomationElement *element = NULL;
CONTROLTYPEID element_type;

GetCursorPos(&pt);
hr = IUIAutomation_ElementFromPoint(pAutomation, pt, &element);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && element != NULL){
   hr = IUIAutomationElement_get_CurrentControlType(element,&element_type);
   if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
     ????    
   }
}
```

As far as I understood with get_CurrentControlType I get the ID of the control type but I am interested in the name of that control type. Could anyone know how to do it?. Tks in advance

Comment: IUIAutomationElement_get_CurrentLocalizedControlType ?

Comment: @Simon Mourier tks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could use [IUIAutomationElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nn-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationelement)::[get_CurrentLocalizedControlType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationelement-get_currentlocalizedcontroltype) instead.

```
BSTR* retVal;
element->get_CurrentLocalizedControlType(&retVal);
```